# Allign divs with float left

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have sample of code in asp.net in `html.beginform`:

```
<div>
    <div style="float:left; width:50%">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Symbol)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Symbol, new { @class = "form-control-inline" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Symbol)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Side)
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Side, "Select", new { @class = "form-control-inline" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Side)
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div style="float:left; width:50%">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Side)
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Side, "Select", new { @class = "form-control-inline" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Side)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Quantity)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Quantity, new { @class = "form-control-inline" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Quantity)
    </div>
</div>
<div @*id="forLimit" hidden*@>
    <div style="float:left; width:50%;">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Symbol)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Symbol, new { @class = "form-control-inline" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Symbol)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Symbol)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Symbol, new { @class = "form-control-inline" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Symbol)
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

and css for `@class = "form-control-inline"`

```
.form-control-inline {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
    width: 50%;
}
```

I do not know why textboxes from last div are divided into two lines. First is in third line, but in second column (should be in first) and because of it second moved to fourth line.

[image: Divided into two lines instead into one]

Comment: are you using bootstrap or cutom css ?

Comment: yes, i am using. Above class is the same as .form-control class from bootstrap, but with width property changed to 50 %. Before there were more changes...

Comment: @gorrch if you are using bootstrap check out [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp) for some info about the grid system and columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use below html structure it will fix your problem

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="usr">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="usr">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="usr">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="usr">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="usr">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="usr">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="usr">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="usr">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```